# Improve ugly scrolling defaults in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I just got a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga 3rd. After using XFCE for several years I decided to give Gnome a chance, so today I donwloaded Ubuntu 22.04 and installed it. Turns out that the scrolling with the touch pad works, but it is not nice as opposed to the case my Xubuntu 20.04 PC. (Sorry for the vague term "nice".)

Issues:

- Missing inertial scroll.
- It is super fast.
- I has some kind of hysteria such that the scrolling is activated after I scrolled a bit. During this bit there is no scrolling, it is kinda for activating the scroll mode.
- Firefox lacks of smooth scroll. (This one I was already able to fix it, just writing it here for the record in case a Gnome/Ubuntu developer sees this. Hard to believe that in 2022 they still ship with non smooth scroll when literally a single command line fixed it... btw it was just `echo MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 | sudo tee -a /etc/environment`.)

How can this be fixed?

It does not look like any kind of issue with the hardware or installation, I think it is just the default settings. But they are really bad ones...

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else wants to improve the ugly scroll defaults in Ubuntu 22.04 (maybe me in the future) here is how: Apparently this is related with the new default of using Wayland instead of Xorg (whatever that exactly is). The solution is simple, just logout and change the session from Wayland to Xorg, it should be something like in the following picture:

[image]

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using Xorg:

```
echo MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

Then re-login.

This gives smooth scrolling in Firefox on Wayland for me.

For smooth scrolling in Chrome go to `chrome://flags`/ and set *Preferred Ozone platform* to *Wayland*.

[image: Check screenshot]